# How to validate input field using php

Tags: php, html, validation, input, field

I've a contact form, and the last field is a math question to be answered from preventing spam emails. what is best way to check if its only a number, no other characters, & answer should be 15. Also ff possible, how make the form clear after its been submitted?

HTML code:

```
<p id="math">10 + 5 =<input type="text" name="answerbox" id="answerbox" value="<?= isset($_POST['answerbox']) ? $_POST['answerbox'] : '' ?>"/></p>
```

I've tried using ctype_digit function, but no luck, didn't work.

```
if(ctype_digit($answerbox != 15) === true){
            $errors[] = "Math answer is not correct.";
          }
```

Full php code:

```
<?php
    if(empty($_POST) === false) {
            $errors = array();
            $name = trim($_POST["name"]);
            $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
            $subject = trim($_POST["subject"]);
            $message = trim($_POST["message"]);
            $answerbox = trim($_POST["answerbox"]); 

            if(empty($name) === true || empty($email) === true || empty($subject) === true || empty($message) === true || empty($answerbox) === true){
            $errors[] = '<p class="formerrors">Please fill in all fields.</p>';
    } else {
        if (strlen($name) > 25) {
           $errors[] = 'Your name is too long.';
        }
        if (ctype_alpha($name) === false) {
           $errors[] = "Your name only should be in letters.";
          }
        if(!preg_match("/^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/i", $email)){
            $errors[] = "Your email address is not valid, please check.";
          }
        if($answerbox != 15){
            $errors[] = "Math answer is not correct.";
          }
        if(empty($errors) === true) {
            $headers =  'From: '.$email. "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: '.$email . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
            mail('me@mymail.me',$subject,$message,$headers);
            print "<p class='formerrors'>Thank you for your message, I'll get back to you shortly!</p>";

        }
    }

}

    ?>
    <?php
        if (empty($errors) === false){
            foreach ($errors as $error) {
                echo'<p class="formerrors">', $error, '</p>';

            }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: look at `is_numeric` http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php for the first problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to check on the calc question:

```php
if(!is_numeric($answerbox) || (int)$answerbox!=15){
    $errors[] = "Math answer is not correct.";
}
```

!is_numeric checks if it's numeric. If not, the message is added to the errors array.
If it's numeric the second condition is checked. (int) casts the variable as integer, so you can check if it's 15 or not.

As for clearing the form: isn't the form automatically cleared when you submit, since you leave/reload the page?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it gives me an error
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&' in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\index.php on line 137
I did it like this
 if (!is_numeric($answerbox != 15)){
            $errors[] = "Math answer is not correct.";
          }
this just ignores the !is_numeric function, even if answer is 15 it displays, the error message. Any ideas?

Comment: What you are doing will not work because what you are testing with `is_numeric()` is not a number/string, but a boolean: the part `$answerbox != 15` evaluates to either true or false, so basically what you're doing is: `is_numeric(true)` or `is_numeric(false)`. This will always evaluate to false. What you need is to test for `$answerbox` directly. I have corrected by code, this way it should work: first you check whether `$answerbox` is numeric, if not the error is given. If it is, it will be parsed to an integer and checked for 15. There was a & instead of a $.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you so much!, its working..I'm not to familiar in php, thanks for ur explanation too. i've test it by typing different characters like 15, then adding $/'"@ ^*, etc  it displays the error, but only fullstop, the code gets ignored, so I added 
(!ctype_digit($answerbox) 
Its now working great!
Thanks once again!